# Advanced search API not returning data for "phonegap" tag

Tags: bug, api-v2, search

I am trying to gather results from the API for the tag `phonegap` but the API is not returning any data.

I am using `/search/advanced` and [get nothing back for November](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?fromdate=1383264000&todate=1385769600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=phonegap&site=stackoverflow):

```
{
  "items": [],
  "quota_remaining": 9942,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

Comment: You can sort by creation and use `min`/`max` which work correctly, I'm not sure what's up with `todate` and `fromdate`.

Comment: Seems to work when I use the questions API looking at it now. Will look into it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like no data from May 2013 onwards:

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/154032/phonegap-posts-by-month

When I search for the `phonegap` tag on SO:

[image: tag search screenshot]

...and click the button I get taken to questions tagged `cordova`:

[image: tag results screenshot]

I suspect the tags have been merged?

Comment: Yes, ["phonegap" was made a synonym of "cordova" on May 23rd, 2013](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/154136/synonym-stats-for-a-given-tag?MasterTagName=cordova).